# Combine multiple sets in a map to unique strings

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I need to combine all strings in all sets of a `Map<String, Set<String>>` to a combination of unique strings. The number of sets can vary, also the number of strings within the sets can vary.

I can't get my head around it. An example code is:

```java
// Create a map
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

// Create setA
Set<String> setA = new HashSet<String>();
setA.add("A");
setA.add("B");
// There could be more (or less) values in setA

// Create setB
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<String>();
setB.add("X");
setB.add("Y");
// There could be more (or less) values in setB

// Create setC
Set<String> setC = new HashSet<String>();
setC.add("1");
setC.add("2");
// There could be more (or less) values in setC

// Add sets to map
map.put("a", setA);
map.put("b", setB);
map.put("c", setC);
// There could be more sets to add to the map
```

```
/*
 * Combine each value from each set in the
 * map {a=[A, B], b=[X, Y], c=[1, 2]} to
 * unique strings. Output should be:
 * A X 1
 * A X 2
 * A Y 1
 * A Y 2
 * B X 1
 * B X 2
 * B Y 1
 * B Y 2
 * ... more combinations if there are more values
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up using the [Guava library for creating the cartesian product](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-). It's easy to use and has a good performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method [`Stream.reduce(accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) for this purpose:

```java
Set<Set<String>> sets = new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of(
        new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of("A", "B")),
        new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of("X", "Y")),
        new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of("1", "2"))));
```

```java
Set<String> set = sets.stream()
        .reduce((s1, s2) -> s1.stream().flatMap(e1 ->
                s2.stream().map(e2 -> e1 + ":" + e2))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)))
        .orElse(Set.of(""));
```

```java
set.forEach(System.out::println);
// A:X:1
// A:X:2
// A:Y:1
// A:Y:2
// B:X:1
// B:X:2
// B:Y:1
// B:Y:2
```